# Excel VBA XL4 Application Level Defined Name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

Defined Names are normally defined at the worksheet or workbook level. But it is also possible to define them at the Application level using an old xl4 macro call. They thus become a place to store state that does not get reset when a VBA project is reset (e.g. due to an error).

This is an old trick, but I cannot remember how to do it. And not much documentation - some people must think that xl4 is obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chip Pearson has it documented here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/hidden.htm